# How to send email with implicit SSL

Tags: c#, ssl, smtp

I can send email with Explicit SSL in C# with SmtpClient, but i cannot send by Implicit SSL(TLS). are there any solution for this.

I want yo use yahoo mail to send a message from my C# program.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057227/c-sharp-asp-net-send-email-via-tls

Comment: You can use explicit TLS with yahoo  on port 587, see https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN4075.html.

Comment: no. i can't. the c sharp code cannot send on port 587. the error is: "Fauiler sending message"

Comment: A short tests (w/o C#) shows that using explicit TLS with smtp.mail.yahoo.com:587 works and there are also [examples for this in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/520998/Send-Email-from-Yahoo-GMail-Hotmail-Csharp). So it might be a problem with your code instead.